# CouchDB calculate sums and averages of group

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, reduce

I have bunch of documents like this:

```
{
   "schema": "property",
   "schema_version": 1,
   "name": "test foobar"
   "account": "1969360",
   "web_data": {
       "conversion_rate": 1.49,
       "average_order_value": 123,
       "visitor_count": 25000,
       "visits_count": 35000,
       "revenue": 50000
   }
}
```

There could be multiple documents with same `account`.

Now I should create MapReduce to calculate average of `web_data.conversion_rate` and `web_data.average_order_value` and sum of `web_data.visitor_count`, `web_data.visits_count` and `web_data.revenue` for each document which has same `account`.

Currently my mapping function emits array like this:

```
['10449266', 'test foobar']
```

where first item is `account` and second `name`.

Emitted value is just `web_data`.

I would like to have output like this:

**GET /list_properties?group_level=1**

```
{
    rows: [
        {
            key: [
                "10449266"
            ],
            value: {
              "property_count": 2,
              "conversion_rate": 1.8625,
              "average_order_value": 153.75,
              "visitor_count": 31250,
              "visits_count": 43750,
              "revenue": 62500
            }
        },
        {
            key: [
                "66294401"
            ],
            value: { ... }
        },
        ...
}
```

How could I achieve this?
Pretty complex pattern, huh?

I've tried so many reduce functions to do this, I'm totally exhausted now. This is one I tried to get started:

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
    return values.reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + b.web_data.revenue;
    });
}
```

That doesn't work as it returns object instead of number. And I have no idea why. It sums up numbers and returns object?

**EDIT:**

I updated reduce function to this:

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
    if(rereduce){
        return values;
    }else{
        var revenue = values.reduce(function(a, b){
            return a + b.web_data.revenue;
        }, 0);

        return {
            revenue       : revenue
        };
    }
}
```

Now I get response like this:

```
{
    "key": [
        "2035864"
    ],
    "value": [
        [
            {
                "revenue": 0
            },
            {
                "revenue": 66321.2
            },
            {
                "revenue": 5319.35
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "revenue": 0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "revenue": 45432.02
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "revenue": 185732.78
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Now if I change `return values` to `return values[0]` in rereduce-part, I get response like:

```
{
    "key": [
        "2035864"
    ],
    "value": {
        "revenue": 0
    }
}
```

**NONSENSE AGAIN!**

Everything I want is just:

```
{
    "key": [
        "2035864"
    ],
    "value": {
        "revenue": 302805.35
    }
}
```

JavaScript allows to do this so easily in browser but I don't understand why CouchDB wants to do things as weirdly as this.

Comment: You need to pass an initial value for your reduce function, so add `0` as the 2nd param to `.reduce()`.

Comment: Okay ... I added that as param. Doesn't seem to help me. Updated question.

Comment: I think I found solution. I'll showing off it later today.

Comment: You also need to make sure you handle the `rereduce` case, your code will break once you hit a decent amount of data.